# Error analysing the csv database with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, ibm-cloud

I'm a doing a project for school using IBM's bluemix and I'm having trouble finding out where is my error. I have a database in CSV that has some parameters (neighbourhood, number of rooms, area in square meters, etc). I also have a JADE file that contains a form that the user have to fill in. In this form, the user will choose how many rooms he wants and everything else. Then, my app in JAVASCRIPT should be able to run the database based on the choices of the user. However, for some reason, the results are not appearing in the webpage as they should.

Here is my code:

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

var fs = require('fs');

var parse = require('csv-parse');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

function seleciona_dados(dados, parametros){
    var resultado = {Bairro: [], quartos: [], area: [], valor: [], endereco: [], img: []};
        for (var i = 1; i < dados.Bairro.length; i++){
            if (dados.Bairro[i] == parametros.bairro && dados.quartos[i] == parametros.quartos && dados.area[i] >= Number(parametros.area) && dados.valor[i] <= Number(parametros.valor)){
                resultado.bairro.push(dados.bairro[i]);
                resultado.quartos.push(dados.quartos[i]);
                resultado.area.push(dados.area[i]);
                resultado.valor.push(dados.valor[i]);
                resultado.endereco.push(dados.endereco[i]);
                resultado.img.push(dados.img[i]);
            }
        }
    return resultado;
}

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {

 // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('cadastro.jade', {  pageTitle: 'Cadastro Usuário'});
});
app.post('/resumo', function(req, res){
    // var furfles = req.body;

    var parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(err, data){
        var dados = {bairro: [], quartos: [], area: [], valor: [], endereco: [], img: []};
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
            dados.bairro.push(data[i][0]);
            dados.quartos.push(data[i][1]);
            dados.area.push(Number(data[i][2]));
            dados.valor.push(Number(data[i][3]));
            dados.endereco.push(data[i][4]);
            dados.img.push(data[i][5]);
        }
        dados = seleciona_dados(dados, req.body);
        res.render('resumo.jade', {pageData:{  pageTitle: 'Resumo do Pedido do Usuário'}, formData: req.body, imoveis: dados});
    });

    fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/static/BD.csv').pipe(parser);
 
});
```

The list of apartments selected in the database should appear below the last sentence of this image.[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvTRz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should start your `for` loops with i = 0 instead of 1. You're missing the first two data records.

Comment: Thank you! However, it didn't solve my problem, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code to:
 - declare `jade` as your template language
 - remove unused code
 - implement a dictionary comparison for `dados`
 - initial async load for your CSV database, see `load_csv_database`
 - Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `equal_to` to filter an the database

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

// CONFIGURE EXPRESS
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// CONFIGURE EXPRESS

var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

var fs = require('fs');
var csvParse = require('csv-parse');

var database;

/**
 * Loads the CSV filename and parse it as JSON Object
 * @param  String filename The csv filename
 * @param  {Function} cb The callback
 */
function load_csv_database(filename, cb) {
  fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(
    csvParse({ delimiter: ';' }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
        return;
      } else {
        var result = {
          bairro: [],
          quartos: [],
          area: [],
          valor: [],
          endereco: [],
          img: []
        };
        data.forEach(function(e) {
          result.bairro.push(e[0]);
          result.quartos.push(e[1]);
          result.area.push(Number(e[2]));
          result.valor.push(Number(e[3]));
          result.endereco.push(e[4]);
          result.img.push(e[5]);
        });
        cb(null, result);
      }
    }));
}

// initial database async load
load_csv_database(__dirname + '/static/BD.csv', function(err, result) {
  if (!err)
    database = result;
  else
    console.log('error:', err);
});

function equal_to(origin) {
  return function compareTo(target) {
    for (var p in origin) {
      if (origin.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        if (origin[p] !== target[p]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    for (var p2 in target) {
      if (target.hasOwnProperty(p2)) {
        if (origin[p2] !== target[p2]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('cadastro', { pageTitle: 'Cadastro Usuário' });
});

app.post('/resumo', function(req, res) {
  // use the global variable "database"
  var result = database.filter(equal_to(req.body));
  res.render('resumo.jade', {
    pageData: { pageTitle: 'Resumo do Pedido do Usuário' },
    formData: req.body,
    imoveis: result
  });
});

app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('server starting on ' + appEnv.url);
});
```